# if and only if condition in awk statement

Tags: awk

This is the wrong syntax but if I wanted to something where the action is done if and only if both conditions are met, how would I do this in awk?

I've tried:

```
awk '{if($1<=28.25&&$2<=28.25){print $0}}'
```

but failed.

Comment: That looks correct (apart from the missing closing quote). How did it fail? BTW, some white space would make that *much* easier to read. Can you update your question to show a *short* input, the output you got, and the output yuou expected?

Comment: Your line is correct, but could be shorten some to `awk '$1<=28.25&&$2<=28.25'`

Comment: bah, Thank you both. I realized the problem I wasn't specifying the field separator.  It worked once I did `awk -F',' '{if ($1<=28.25&&$2<=28.25) {print $0}}'`

Comment: now update it to just `awk -F',' '$1<=28.25 && $2<=28.25'` and you've got yourself an **awk** script :-).

Comment: You don't even need to quote `,`.  This should work fine `awk -F, '$1<=28.25 && $2<=28.25'`

Answer (score 0):

Awk uses { print $0 } as a default action, so you can simply write:

```
awk -F, '$1 <= 28.25 && $2 <= 28.25' inputFile
```

[An omitted action is equivalent to `{ print $0 }`](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/gawk-3.1.0/html_chapter/gawk_8.html#SEC116)